# Como colocar um form dentro de uma tab?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Quero adicionar um form dentro de um *tab*, já tentei usar o comando "this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(new form1);" e não deu certo, como proceder?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Isto não é possível, o `Form` é uma janela, e uma janela é o que tem de maior em uma aplicação desktop GUI, portanto não tem como algo menor, uma aba, incorporar algo maior.

Deve planejar o conteúdo de outra forma que encaixe dentro da aba. Na verdade nem é preciso muita coisa, tudo o que iria colocar no `Form` coloque dentro da `Tab`.